# Machine Key generation feature not exist in latest IIS Version

Tags: asp.net, iis

Answering one of the recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260435/mvc-antiforgerytoken-machinekey-for-encryption/25260767#25260767) on SO, i encountered this anomaly.

This [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx) suggests using IIS to generate machine key, which looks more secure to me as Microsoft tool being used. However, it seems this feature is only supported until IIS 7 or less.

I don't find it on my box IIS 8.5. I checked on IIS 7.5 and its not present there either. However, I found it in IIS 6.1 on a coworker box.

I am wondering whether:

1. It still exist in IIS latest versions, if yes, how to use it?
2. If it is removed from latest version of IIS, what's suggested approach from Microsoft to generate a secure enough machine key?
3. Is it safe to use these custom generators?

   a. [Machine Key Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) (online)

   b. [ASP.NET machineKey Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16645/ASP-NET-machineKey-Generator) (tool you can modify)

Answer (score 10):

See https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218#AppendixA for information on how to generate a `<machineKey>` element.  There's a script there that you can copy & paste into a Powershell window.

Reminder: only use keys that you generated yourself on your own machine.  Never use an online generator.

Comment: Thanks Levi, +1 for pointing me to Powershell script. I am just curious to know about IIS support as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with PowerShell. Could you tell me how do you run that script? I've been searching on the web, but can make it spit out the key.

Comment: For anyone that sees this, I was just as confused as gligoran.  Turns out you can just copy and paste the script into powershell, press enter and then the next line type Generate-MachineKey and it spits out the web.config code.  It was a little slow on my computer, but might be different on yours.

Answer (score 3):

As for mentioned by @ryanulit, you can just copy the script directly to your PowerShell window

Steps :

1. Open powershell window (anywhere is fine)
2. Copy the script from the microsoft link and paste in your powershell window and press enter
3. Type `Generate-MachineKey -validationAlgorithm SHA1`
4. That's it. Your machine key description will show up in the window.
   [PowerShell image sample from my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3MfH.png)

Script Link from Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218#AppendixA

Answer (score 1):

I know I came to very late to provide this answer. Hope this helps for any others.

I'm using the latest IIS 10(*which is the latest*)

By default, the **Machine Key** feature is not installed when enabling the `Internet Information Service` in the windows features.

You need to install **ASP.NET XX** from the `World Wide Web Service`

[image]

After installing this, you can generate your keys from the `Machine Key` Option.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the `administration.config` file in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`.  Then, in the `<moduleProviders>` node under `<!-- ASP.NET Modules-->` remove the `MachineKey` node.  Then run `iisreset`.  Re-open IIS and see if the ASP.NET area is present.  If it is, put the `MachineKey` node back in the `administration.config` file (or just re-instate the original config file) and run `iisreset` again.