# MVC4 to MV5 machine key validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

After migrating my mvc4 project to mvc5 using the microsoft following this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I have to following error message:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'When using
>    or the
>   MachineKey.Protect and MachineKey. Unprotect APIs, the 'validation'
>   attribute must be one of these values: SHA1, HMACSHA256, HMACSHA384,
>   HMACSHA512, or alg:[KeyedHashAlgorithm].

This is the machine key config:  validation="AES" decryption="AES".
My project is using framework 4.7.2. When I change the validation to SHA1 and decrypt to AUTO is works.
I am required to make it work with AES thought and I am not sure why it works with mvc 4 and not 5.
I also tried adding the framework 4.7 in the httpRuntime config in the web.config and get the same error.
Any idea? Thank you.

**New Status 27-09-2019**

I added a line just before the exception is raised (Before using @Html.AntiForgeryToken()) to validate that the machine key configuration from the web config has the expected value while debugging.

```
MachineKeySection section = (MachineKeySection) 
  ConfigurationManager.GetSection ("system.web/machineKey");
```

The compatibility mode is set to "Framework20SP2", but I still get the error message saying that compatibilityMode is Framework45.

Web.Config

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="AES" decryption="AES" />
```

**New Status 01-10-2019**
I just created a branch off a working state of my application. When checking the value of

```
MachineKeySection section = (MachineKeySection) 
ConfigurationManager.GetSection ("system.web/machineKey");
```

The compatiblity mode is "Framework20SP2", as soon as I upgrade to MVC5, it becomes "Framework45". This means that one of the updated packages for MVC5 forces the new compatiblity mode, even if it is specified otherwise in the web.config.

Comment: I commented out all targetFramework configurations in the web.config to make sure the compatibilityMode is not used and it does not change anything. Adding compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" to the web.config does not help either.

Comment: machineKey is set in system.web part of the web.config. well not enough code to tel from the above. this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260435/mvc-antiforgerytoken-machinekey-for-encryption, mainly the llnk to generate one, i think the link has change since i last used, use https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/ASP-Net-MachineKey-Generator.aspx

Comment: This is my web.config

    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" validationKey="..." 
    decryptionKey="..." validation="AES" decryption="AES" />

I don't need to generate one it is specified in the web.config.

Comment: unsure of what Framework20SP2 is do you need it? take that out... you probably need to regen ur key for dotney=t 4.5. see the link i gave... which implies different keys for different version of dotnet. i am using 4.5 key with mine and im on 4.7.2m

Comment: The project did not change .net version, it was 4.7.2 in mvc4 and the same after updating to mvc5. The only thing that changed is I tried adding the compatibility mode Framework20SP2, because the error message says that the compatibilityMode Framework45 does not work with AES validation. If no compatibility mode is set in the machinekey node it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2/) - The  validation value must be SHA1 (which we interpret as HMACSHA1), HMACSHA256, HMACSHA384, HMACSHA512, or a reference to a KeyedHashAlgorithm-derived type. The values AES, 3DES, and MD5 are no longer allowed, as they were in ASP.NET 4.

May be there is some solution with machieKey compatability mode..

Comment: It was working fine before my upgrade to MVC5 though and the project was using .net 4.7.2.